# Searchable Activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, search

I am trying to gather as much information as I can about creating a search interface in Android Studio. I am working with developer.android.com and have a question about using the search interface.

I quote:

```
<application ... >
<!-- this is the searchable activity; it performs searches -->
<activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>

<!-- this activity enables the search dialog to initiate searches
     in the SearchableActivity -->
<activity android:name=".OtherActivity" ... >
    <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
</activity>
...
```

"If you want every activity in your application to provide the search dialog, insert the above meta-data element as a child of the application element, instead of each activity. This way, every activity inherits the value, provides the search dialog, and delivers searches to the same searchable activity."

I don't understand the first sentence, unfortunately. What do I have to do exactly in order to have my search dialog in every activity. In this code example, we only have the search dialog in one activity. Can anyone show me using the code above, how to insert meta-data as a child of the application element in my AndroidManifest.xml?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just describes an easy way of doing things.

You add the `<meta-data>` element to every activity that you want to have this behaviour of providing a serach dialog. However, if all your activities have this behaviour, instead of adding the `<meta-data>` element to all of them, you can just add it to the `<application>` and it'll work as if you added it to all `<activity>`s. Just add it to your application like:

```
<application
  android:name=".MyApp"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
  <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
...
</application>
```